# Using hidden template and getting the Error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender, yajsw

I'm new to JsViews... I used http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrplaying method to create my template. but instead of adding my template inside the  I've added in the hidden . Now for the hidden template I'm getting the "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - //%7B%7B:URL%7D%7D?new={{:magicNumber}}" which is related to the URL source as it is not exist in hidden template .... {{:URL}...umber}} I'm just wondering how I can get of this error from the console (inspect element)

Comment: Your question needs to provide much more information - including the template markup that caused the URL error (with {{:magicNumber}}, or a simple example of your problem using jsfiddle. Not sure what you mean by the hidden div, but see my answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a template in a hidden div rather than a script block is not a good idea. If the template includes things like `<img src="{{:...}}" />`. then the browser will try to load the img from a non-existant URL. In a script block, the markup is just treated as text - so avoids side-effects like that.

Comment: Many thanks I've just used the script block and it's works... Thanks for answering my Question :)