# Prefill jsrender template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender

How to render the select (having the option) as part of the table?

```js
$('select').append($('<option>').text('single'));
$('table').append($('#rowTmpl').render({name:'peter'}));
```

```css
th,td {border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/master/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none" id="statis">
  <select></select>
</div>
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <tr>
    <td>{{:name}}</td>
    <td>{{include tmpl=#statis /}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Stat</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first javascript line appends an option to the select (4th html-line).
The second javascript line should render a row to the table for the person `peter`.

Problem:

1. I can not make the div to a script-tag because the first javascript line will not find the select-tag.
2. I can not render the div via the `{{include` because #statis is a div and not a script-tag.

Comment: can you explain more ?!

Comment: Expected is a table with Name and Stat having name `Peter` and in the second column a select-field to choose the stat. JSRender is a template engine using json to render html, to render the data-row of the table. What exactly to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your {{include}} has a syntax error. It should be:

```
<td>{{include tmpl="#statis" /}}</td>
```

In fact you can  declare a JsRender template in a hidden div, but it is generally not good practice, since there can be side effects. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609895/1054484.

You can also declare templates from strings - and dynamically manipulate the string beforehand if you want.

See also:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl
- http://www.jsviews.com/#tagsyntax@composition

```js
$('select').append($('<option>').text('single'));
$('table').append($('#rowTmpl').render({name:'peter'}));
```

```css
th,td {border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/master/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none" id="statis">
  <select></select>
</div>
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <tr>
    <td>{{:name}}</td>
    <td>{{include tmpl="#statis" /}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Stat</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/tmpl told me my syntax was correct....

Comment: Well no, tmpl=#content in that sample is not a jQuery selector, but rather uses view.content. See http://www.jsviews.com/#tagsyntax@wrap. That's why it doesn't have quotes. #content is view.content - see view paths: http://www.jsviews.com/#paths

Comment: I had no time to understand and no time to teach others if i did. Anyway good work and thanks for the fish.